# spring boot application(profile specific).properties returns null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to load profile specific property file values using springboot to my @webservice class. I followed the below steps,

1)

```
created application.properties with profile to be active
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

2)

```
Created application-dev.properties with following values
username = XXXXXXX
password = XXXXXXX
host = XXXXXXX
port = XXXXXXX
welcome.message = Development
```

3)

```
 Created @Springbootapplication class
```

4)

```
Created @configuration class for appconfig
```

5) Started reading values of application-dev.properties in the appconfig class using

code:

```
public class AppConfig {
@Value("${welcome.message}")
 private String welcomeMsg;
 @Profile("dev")
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSourceDev() {
System.out.println("****Dev Profile called*****"+welcomeMsg);
```

when i run from spring tool suite, for the first time welcome message printed successfully in console.

"****Dev Profile called*****Development"

But when I try to read the property values from the @webservice class I created,through soap UI,

Code:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "SampleIF", endpointInterface   = "com.tc.services.sample.cxf.SampleIF")
public class SampleIFImpl implements SampleIF {
@Value("${welcome.message}")
private String welcomeMsg;
    @Override
public Contact CreateContract(Details details) {
    System.out.println("****Welcome Message Val*****"+welcomeMsg);
```

Either it fails at appconfig.class by throwing the following exception

1)

```
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'welcome.message' in value "${welcome.message}"
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:379)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1348)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:88)
```

2) Or @webservice class with null value

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: That error message is pointing to your `AppConfig` class, not the `SampleIFImpl` class.

Comment: A sample reproducing the issue would be helpful.

Comment: @nickb: Agreed as I mentioned in exception 1, but will you plz help me on understanding why it fails...since when i ran from sts run as spirng boot app...the logs printed in the console was having the property value but when i try to execute through soap ui for the same property it is throughing exception.

Comment: @Indraneel Bende: How do you want me to share the sample?

Comment: prefer github for samples.

Comment: I think your property file name should be application.dev.properties

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the escenario but I did some changes in the implementation

this is my application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active:
    - dev
```

And this is my application-dev.yml

```
welcome:
  message: Development
```

Finally I´m using the variable directly from the class where the value is needed

```
@Value("${welcome.message}")
private String welcomeMsg;
```

Comment: ElChava: Thanks for your response, I tried the same approach but I used .properties instead of .yml. It was working fine for me as well for the first run while deploying war local from spring tool suite and welcome message printed as excepted, since I added the value(welcome.message) in my appconfig.class. But after the deployment i tried to execute the webservice I created as part of war from soap UI but at that time same @value defined in appconfig.class returns null.

Comment: If you deployed the application, can you see the profiles active: dev in your logs ??

Comment: Elchava: Please find below logs where I am printing the value of welcome.message based on active profile. While deploying and starting the server.[2m2018-06-07 10:03:54.682[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m9864[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main]
Profile called*****DEV_PROFILE

Answer (score 0):

instead of `application.yml` try giving `application.yaml`
It worked for me for the same issue like your's one

Comment: Pay attention to punctuation and use code formatting for file names

Answer (score 0):

try to open terminal, type mvn clean install and it worked for me